# How to use search efficiently with the keyboard in Internet Explorer 9 Beta?

Tags: search, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 combined address and search bar into the One Box which leaves me with a problem. Previously I have done searching by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, entering my search term, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, selecting the search provider (e.g. I have Wikipedia (de) and Wikipedia (en) in there which made the list with text nice, since both have the same icon) and hitting Enter.

That behavior seems to be gone now. What remains is the list of icons below the suggestions (which is why they jump up and down as IE gives me suggestions – which is why I have found them always hard to focus on). Apparently my previous habit still seems to work somewhat, with the exception that I now have to use <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> to navigate the list of search providers – and the dotted selection square is a quite subtly focus indicator there.

Are there better options I just didn't notice so far? Using the mouse is out of question, actually since I rarely type using my mouse.